Rendering mathematical formulae using LaTeX in UWP (Universal Windows Platform) applications
I'm looking for a NuGet package or a library for rendering LaTeX formulae in UWP (Universal Windows Platform) applications, something similar to XAML-Math. Does anybody know about such a component?

Do UWP applications and/or XAML-Math employ MathJax as the rendering engine? If so, your query is off-topic for this site.

welcome! mathjax doesn't use tex, even though it employs a similar syntax, so you need to clarify whether you are really talking about latex here. I strongly suspect this is not the best place to ask for something like this anyway .... (just given the people who tend to answer questions.)
